# Reactjs: How to cycle through an array of objects in a component?

Tags: reactjs

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have an api that will return an array of JSON objects (popular movies from TMdb), I want to display 1 movie (the title and poster image) at a time and then when a "next" button is clicked display the next movie in the array.

Here is my react component and it works as expected, but I feel like I'm not doing it the right way. Any insight is much appreciated.

```
var PopularMovies = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        title: '',
        posterUrl: '',
        index: 0
    };
},

nextMovie: function() {
    var index = this.state.index;
    index++;

    var movie = this.state.movies[index];

    this.setState({
        index: index,
        title: movie.title,
        posterUrl: 'http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w154/' + movie.poster_path
    });
},

componentDidMount: function() {

    $.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/popular_movies', function(res) {
        if (this.isMounted()) {
            this.setState({
                movies: res,
                title: res[this.state.index].title,
                posterUrl: 'http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w154/' + res[this.state.index].poster_path
            });
        }
    }.bind(this));
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={this.state.posterUrl} />
            <h3>{this.state.title}</h3>
            <button onClick={this.nextMovie}>Next</button>
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

Comment: Why not? If it works then it works - You don't need to store the movie title in state just the next/current index. Furthermore in your `componentDidMount` referencing `this.state.index` will always yield 0.

Comment: Looks fine to me. But an unrelated suggestion I have is, to find a mechanism to store the `http://localhost:3000` in a separate config/constants module ... which you may already considered though.